# My DatePicker does not work in all browsers

Tags: javascript, input, browser, asp.net-mvc-5, datepicker

I have a datepicker that does not work in Safari, Firefox, but that works very well with Chrome, Edge, do I have to change my way or there is a way to adjust my code to keep it DatePicker that I use, but that it adjusts according to the browsers used?

#### HTML

```html
<div class="row col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.BirthDate, Resource.BirthDate, new { @class = "" })
    <div class="input-group">
      @Html.EditorFor(model => model.BirthDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "true"} })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BirthDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
      <div class="input-group-text">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=datetime]').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd/M/yy",
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: "-60:+0"
  });
});
```

#### View Model

```cs
[Display(Name = "BirthDate")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MMM/yyyy}")]
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

So, users trying to enter their birthdates in a browser different from Chrome and Edge, click in the rectangle and no calendar appears

Comment: So you are using the [jQuery.fn.datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) plugin?

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl yes